# What is LocalTableScan in Spark Structured Streaming for?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

does anyone know to what corresponds LocalTableScan in Spark Structured Streaming?

I'm trying to understand a strange behavior that I observed in my Spark structure streaming application that is running in local[*] mode.

I have 8 core on my machines. While the majority of my Batches have 8 partitions, every once in a while I get 16 or 32 or 56 and so on partitions/Tasks. I notice that it is always a multiple of 8. I have notice in opening the stage tab, that when it happens, it is because there is multiple LocalTableScan.

That is if I have 2 LocalTableScan then the mini-batch job, will have 16 task/partition and so on.

To give a bit of context because I am suspecting that it might come from it, I am using a MemoryStream.

```
val rows = MemoryStream[Map[String,String]]
val df = rows.toDF()
val rdf = df.mapPartitions{ it => {.....}}(RowEncoder.apply(StructType(List(StructField("blob", StringType, false)))))
```

I have a future that feeds my memory stream as such right after:

```
Future {
    blocking {
      for (i <- 1 to 100000) {
        rows.addData(maps)
        Thread.sleep(3000)
      }
    }
  }
```

and then my query:

```
rdf.writeStream.
    trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 seconds"))
    .format("console").outputMode("append")
    .queryName("SourceConvertor1").start().awaitTermination()
```

Please, any suggestions? Hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates in memory on the Driver. As your code shows.

Comment: Hi @thebluephantom Thank you so much for taking the time to help. Meanwhile, would you please expend further on what you mean: "It indicates in memory on the Driver" ? Do you mean it means, that spark is scanning the data from an in-memory table that is situated on the driver ? Any idea why then, for one mini-batch I get 2 scans ? 2 fetch ? in other words one mini-batch seems to correspond to 2 batches being fetched/scan from the MemoryStream. Does that make any sense to you ?

Comment: I answered the title of the question. You need to ask a new question.

Comment: From what I have gathered it seems to me that the job schedule let say 32 tasks/partitions but is effectively performing 8 tasks at the time which make sense because of the number of core available. However, i don't see what the damn correlation with the number of scan/fetch from the in-memory table? Why would it do multiple Scan when it has todo one mini-batch job every second ? I just don't understand that. I mean the link is weird, because it could well do 2 scan but than feed it as one batch to the job, hence having big partition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241337/how-the-number-of-tasks-and-partitions-is-set-when-using-memorystream

Comment: On hols, will look later as interesting.

Comment: I grant you that it is not easy to follow this Spark. I am learning every day myself as u r I suspect, but 8 cores seems a good starting point in your analysis.